# Prevent the stretching from changing cells border in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

Is it possible to prevent the stretching from changing cells border in Google spreadsheet?

I mean that if I stretch a cell which has a border above it, then the same border will be added to the cells where I am stretching the current cell and if the cell which I am stretching does not have a border below (just for instance) then the cells to which I stretch will have their lower borders removed (in case they had the lower borders).

I want to always have such a stretching that would prevent the border change. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "streching"? can you describe this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can remove border by:**

- **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>\</kbd>** (which removes all formatting)
- **<kbd>LEFT ALT</kbd>** + **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>6</kbd>** (which removes all borders)

**note:** **<kbd>6</kbd>** not **<kbd>num 6</kbd>**

[image]

Comment: I am sorry you did not understand my question. I want the border to stay and not be removed in the cell (into which I am stretching a formula) once I stretch a formula (from a cell without the border) into a cell with the border. Thank you.

Comment: @iamyourfriend I did understand you. the thing is that there is no way how to achieve this without border being cloned to the next cells. al you can do is to highlight them back and remove border/formatting with a keyboard shortcut